# How to structure your Parse data model for a classic Post and Comment model? (using iOS, Swift, Parse)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, data-modeling, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

Working on a blog-like iPhone app using Swift (with a Storyboard) and Parse and have been struggling for several weeks now in developing a comment/reply system similar to the Facebook iOS app and other social network apps.

**Is my current Parse data model structure set up appropriately to have this type of functionality where users can create posts and comment/reply on posts?** (ie: not sure how many classes/tables to create, if I have the right columns, if I'm using the correct data types, etc). My goal is to set it up so that there is a relationship between a Post and its comments/replies (also who authored the post, comment, etc).

Currently in Parse, I have the following three tables in the Parse data browser:

**User table** (given by Parse):
[image]

**Post table**
[image]

**Reply table**
[image]

Please forgive any complexity...if something is not clear, please ask!

Thank you for your time! I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: What is the real question?  I see "I am not sure how to" then 2 paragraphs.

Comment: @Khnle-Kevin , thanks for the feedback. I have just revised my question to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the users post on your Reply page try this code below:

```
  print(replyPost)
print(replyPost?.objectForKey("message"))
self.userMessage!.text = replyPost?.objectForKey("postMessage") as? String ?? "nil"
print(replyPost?.objectForKey("userName"))
 self.userName!.text = replyPost?.objectForKey("postUser") as? String ?? "nil"
```